# Extract a line if it contains a word in a specified column

Tags: unix, grep, text-files, extract, multiple-columns

I want to extract a line if it contains a word in a specified column of a textfile. **How can i do it on a one-liner unix command to do it?** Maybe with `cat`, `echo`, `cut`, `grep` with several piples or something.

I have a textfile that looked with this format

```
#SentenceID<tab>Sentence1<tab>Sentence2<tab>Other_unknown_number_of_columns<tab> ...
```

An example of the textfile looks like this:

```
021348  this is the english sentence with coach .   c'est la phrase française avec l'entraîneur .   And then there are several nonsense columns like these  .
923458  this is a another english sentence without the word .   c'est une phrase d'une autre anglais sans le bus mot .  whatever foo bar    nonsense columns    2134234 $%^&
```

The command should output if the word i am looking for is `coach` in the 2nd column:

```
021348  this is the english sentence with coach .   c'est la phrase française avec l'entraîneur .   And then there are several nonsense columns like these  .
```

I can do it with python as such, but i'm looking for a unix command or something one-liner:

```
outfile = open('out.txt')
for line in open('in.txt'):
  if "coach" in line.split():
    print>>outfile, line
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
awk -F'\t' '{if($2 ~ "coach") print} your_file
```

- `-F'\t'` --> makes the delimiter to be the tab.
- `$2 ~ "coach"` --> looks for "coach" in the second field.
- `print $0` or `print` --> prints the whole line.

**Edit**

[sudo_O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066031/sudo-o) has suggested the following, which is even shorter:

```
awk -F'\t' '$2~/coach/' file
```

Comment: +1 but note awks default block is `{print}` so all you need is `awk -F'\t' '$2~/coach/' file`

Comment: Nice to learn that, @sudo_O! I update my answer with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of needs I always use awk :

> awk -F'\t' '$2 ~ /coach/ {print $0;}' < textFile

You have access to all columns with $x, $0 contains the entire line. The test is made with regexp, quite simple in this case, so it's really powerfull if your need gets more complicated.